# Matching a List which has dictionary items based on a specific list to return a modified list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, search

I want to match a List which has items that are a dictionary with another list of strings, if there is a match then the whole entry of the list stays or pops.

For example this is the list:

```py
list= [{'label': 'Fund.SharedClass.FOR ALL SICRIPTIONS:', 'type':
'radios', 'value': 'FOR ALL SICRIPTIONS:', 'group':
'Fund.SharedClass', 'overlay': {'page': 2, 'left': 261, 'top': 200,
'height': 12, 'width': 11}}, {'label': 'Fund.SharedClass.Class A
Dollar Shares', 'type': 'radios', 'value': 'Class A Dollar Shares',
'group': 'Fund.SharedClass', 'overlay': {'page': 2, 'left': 689,
'top': 276, 'height': 23, 'width': 28}}, {'label':
'Fund.SharedClass.Class A Dollar Shares', 'type': 'radios', 'value':
'Class A Dollar Shares', 'group': 'Fund.SharedClass', 'overlay':
{'page': 2, 'left': 688, 'top': 275, 'height': 25, 'width': 30}},
{'label': 'Fund.SharedClass.Class A Sterling Shares', 'type':
'radios', 'value': 'Class A Sterling Shares', 'group':
'Fund.SharedClass', 'overlay': {'page': 2, 'left': 689, 'top': 313,
'height': 23, 'width': 28}}, {'label': 'Fund.SharedClass.Class A
Sterling Shares', 'type': 'radios', 'value': 'Class A Sterling
Shares', 'group': 'Fund.SharedClass', 'overlay': {'page': 2, 'left':
688, 'top': 312, 'height': 25, 'width': 30}}, {'label':
'Fund.SharedClass.Class B Dollar Shares', 'type': 'radios', 'value':
'Class B Dollar Shares', 'group': 'Fund.SharedClass', 'overlay':
{'page': 2, 'left': 689, 'top': 353, 'height': 23, 'width': 28}},
{'label': 'Fund.SharedClass.Class B Dollar Shares', 'type': 'radios',
'value': 'Class B Dollar Shares', 'group': 'Fund.SharedClass',
'overlay': {'page': 2, 'left': 688, 'top': 352, 'height': 25, 'width':
30}}]
```

I want to match the list[0]['label'] which a string value with another list say list2:

```py
list2= ['Class B Sterling Non-Voting Shares', 'Class B Dollar
Non-Voting Shares', 'Class Allar Non-Voting Shares', 'Class A Dollar
Non-Voting Shares', 'Class B Sterling Shares', 'Class B Dollar
Shares', 'Class A Sterling Shares', 'Class A Dollar Shares']
```

If there is a match with one of the terms of list2 with the list one elements of `['label']` then that entry stays in the list and replace by the matched value of list2, else the whole entry pops from the list retaining only the entries which has a match of `['label']` with list2.

I have tried to iterate through to find the items but failed to return the desired result. If anyone can help.

```py
def model(list):
    list2= ['Class B Sterling Non-Voting Shares', 'Class B Dollar Non-Voting 
            Shares', 'Class Allar Non-Voting Shares', 'Class A Dollar Non-Voting 
            Shares', 'Class B Sterling Shares', 'Class B Dollar Shares', 'Class A 
            Sterling Shares', 'Class A Dollar Shares']
    res = [val for key, val in list[0]['label'] if list2 in key]
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing right now is checking to see if the entire `list2` is present in the string `key`. If I understand right, what you want to do is check if any of the elements of `list2` are in `key`.

In addition, `list[0]['label']` is just a string, and you can't unpack it into `key, val`.

Try something like this:

```
def isElementOfListInString(a_list, a_string):
    for element in a_list:
        if element in a_string:
            return True
    return False
```

And then modify your current code to say:

```
res = [dictionary for dictionary in list if isElementOfListInString(list2, dictionary['label'])]
```

Alternatively, it looks like the `'value'` in the dictionary contains the part of the label you want to match with, so you might be able to just do this:

```
res = [dictionary for dictionary in list if dictionary['value'] in list2]
```

The output from both of these is:

```
[
  {'label': 'Fund.SharedClass.Class A Dollar Shares', 'type': 'radios', 'value': 'Class A Dollar Shares', 'group': 'Fund.SharedClass', 'overlay': {'page': 2, 'left': 689, 'top': 276, 'height': 23, 'width': 28}}, 
  {'label': 'Fund.SharedClass.Class A Dollar Shares', 'type': 'radios', 'value': 'Class A Dollar Shares', 'group': 'Fund.SharedClass', 'overlay': {'page': 2, 'left': 688, 'top': 275, 'height': 25, 'width': 30}}, 
  {'label': 'Fund.SharedClass.Class A Sterling Shares', 'type': 'radios', 'value': 'Class A Sterling Shares', 'group': 'Fund.SharedClass', 'overlay': {'page': 2, 'left': 689, 'top': 313, 'height': 23, 'width': 28}}, 
  {'label': 'Fund.SharedClass.Class A Sterling Shares', 'type': 'radios', 'value': 'Class A Sterling Shares', 'group': 'Fund.SharedClass', 'overlay': {'page': 2, 'left': 688, 'top': 312, 'height': 25, 'width': 30}}, 
  {'label': 'Fund.SharedClass.Class B Dollar Shares', 'type': 'radios', 'value': 'Class B Dollar Shares', 'group': 'Fund.SharedClass', 'overlay': {'page': 2, 'left': 689, 'top': 353, 'height': 23, 'width': 28}}, 
  {'label': 'Fund.SharedClass.Class B Dollar Shares', 'type': 'radios', 'value': 'Class B Dollar Shares', 'group': 'Fund.SharedClass', 'overlay': {'page': 2, 'left': 688, 'top': 352, 'height': 25, 'width': 30}}
]
```

Comment: From the final list, is there anyway i can remove the duplicated entries based on the list[0]['label'] values? @pslessard